# MySQL using Bind_Param and ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: mysql, bindparam

I have a table called `test_favorites`where users are able to add something to favorites. I use this `SQL-function`, 
but get this error:

> call to a member function `bind_param()` on boolean in line (bind_param-line)

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `test_favorites` (`What`, `OId`, `UserId`) VALUES (?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Values(`Value`)=Values(`Value`)*(-1);");
$sql->bind_param('sis',$posttype, $postid  , $sessionuserid);
```

I dont know if solving the error solves my problem. Because in my table `test_favorites` the columns `What`, `OId`and `UserId` are uniqe. In the column `Value` I have assigned the default value to 1. But I am trying to make a SQL which are checking if `What`, `OId`and `UserId` already exists, and if it exist, then the script should multiply the value in `value` with (-1). So in that way `Value` switches between 1 and -1. If it dont exists then the default value should be printed in column `value`.

Am I writing the SQL sentence wrong?

**EDIT**
After som starthelp I now use this code:

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `test_favorites` (`What`, `OId`, `UserId`, `Value`) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Value=values(Value)*(-1);");
$sql->bind_param('sisi',$posttype, $postid,$sessionuserid,$one);
```

I seem to get closer, but it still does not update, just adds one new row to the table.

Comment: The `Insert into`worked well before I inserted `ON DUPLICATE KEY`.

Comment: $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `test_favorites` (`What`, `OId`, `UserId`, `Value`) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Value=values(Value)*(-1);");
$sql->bind_param('sisi',$posttype, $postid,$sessionuserid,$one);

This is my last code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, valid syntax for `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is

```
INSERT INTO `test_favorites` (`What`, `OId`, `UserId`) VALUES (?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE userId = values(userId) * -1, anyotherfield = values(What) + values(OId);
```

So in your case - you can update any field in the table, but can use  values SQL function on the three ones you're actually inserting

Comment: Okey, so i tried to adapt and wrote this:
$sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO test_favorites (What, OId, UserId, Value) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Values(Value)=Values(Value)*-1;"); $sql->bind_param('sisi',$posttype, $postid,$sessionuserid,1);

Comment: Okay, you again wrote it incorrect. `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = value * -1`

Comment: Thank you. I seem to get closer, but it just adds one new row, not updates the exisiting one.

Comment: So I have once again changed the SQL with your help: 
$sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `test_favorites` (`What`, `OId`, `UserId`, `Value`) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Value=values(Value)*(-1);");
$sql->bind_param('sisi',$posttype, $postid,$sessionuserid,$one);

But still it just adds one new row instead of editing the existing one.

Comment: In that case check the indices. If `on duplicate key update ` wasn't triggered it means values you insert weren't present in table...

Comment: You are absolutely right!  I changed `What` to Char(3) and Unique and that solved it. BUT (!), now i got it to update, so it multiplies it with -1. But when the `Value` is -1 it will not go back to 1.

Comment: So let's clarify it - if you need to multiply value of `value` column that is currently in table it's `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = value * -1`, if you want to multiply value of `value` column that you are __currently inserting__ - it's `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = values(value) * -1`

Comment: `$one = 1`. So if row dont exist it should insert value = 1. If it exist it should  multiply it with (-1). In that way it will be either 1 or -1. So it is a kind of boolean. (-1) * (-1) = 1 and 1 * (-1) = -1.

Comment: I solved it with: $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `test_favorites` (`What`, `OId`, `UserId`, `IntValue`) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE IntValue = CASE WHEN IntValue < 1 
                                    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END");